# Notifications on lockscreen before API 21

Tags: android, notifications

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) notifications in the lockscreen were only implemented in API 21, but my brother has a Galaxy S2 running android 4.1 and it shows notifications on the lockscreen without any lockscreen customizing app, does the support library allow notifications on lockscreen or how do we implement it?

Comment: I don't know specifics of API 21 or that model, but I believe Samsung are known for heavily customising the "stock" Android in their devices, so -- in effect -- it probably _does_ have a custom lockscreen app.

Comment: So you're saying that it's possible that the android version that samsung produces supports notifications in the lockscreen before before api 21?

Comment: My _guess_ is that they've got a customised lockscreen app (as part of their TouchWiz package) that can display pre-API 21 notifications on the lockscreen.